# ValueError: SQL query parameters should be a tuple, list or dict

Tags: python, odoo

**Edited code in a correct way. Now it's working.**

Here is my code:

```
def _random_letter(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context):
    num=[]
    for i in range(5):
        res = random.choice([1, 2, 3, 5, 9])
        num.append(res)
        print  (num)
        return num

def _mytest_query(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context):
    cr.execute("""update checkroll_plucker set worker_name =concat('worker','%s') where id='1'""", self._random_letter(cr, uid, ids, name, args, context))
    cr.commit()
```

Also, I am still confused about which parameters to pass to functions. I go through a developer book, but haven't got clear idea. I will mention those below please correct me if they correct.

Example:

```
self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context

self = call to current class of that method called 
cr = current row in the table 
uid = user id for check if he authorized or not for run this function 
name = column name we need to insert 
context = language/time details (but what is the use of it.more times it equals to None)
```

Comment: You are running the loop 5 times in `_random_letter` but the return statement would cause it to execute one time, returning an integer (5 in your case) which is not acceptable. Acceptable forms as suggested by error message are `tuple`, `list` or `dict`.

Comment: thanks jitendra.
then what is your suggestion

Comment: It isn't clear from your program, what parameter are you trying to pass to the sql query. If you could specify that may be someone will be in better position to help you.

Comment: u told me that need to return list tuple of dict
ik i'll try in that way and let u know.why its always need list objectives to write

Comment: @jitendra
thanks now its works friend..i modified the code and added it

Answer (score 0):

put

```
self._random_letter in (,)
```

Repair Bug

```
cr.execute("""update checkroll_plucker set worker_name =concat('worker','%s') where id='1'""", (self._random_letter,)(cr, uid, ids, name, args, context))
```

To pass parameters in tuples , That is to use (arg,)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).